# Get form data posted back from another website in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I'm redirecting to a payment form which is hosted on a bank page.
This is the code I use to do that:

```
const form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = "post";
form.action = `https://epay.mybank.com/fim/est3Dgate`;
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
form.remove();
```

Now once the payment is successfully done on the bank website, per their documentation they are posting back to the success page, here is the documentation:

[image]

And the response parameters:

[image]

How I can get the response parameter values once the page will be reached on our side in Angular?

Comment: I guess you would need to send the **okUrl** paramter in your initial request. E.g *myDomain.com/paymentResponse* that page then needs to be able to handle the posted response parameters

Comment: @Lapskaus - I'm doing that, and the redirect works fine, I'm more interested how to capture the data which the bank is sending back such as the Response and AuthCode, thanks

Comment: Your Backend has to do that, the bank can not post the data directly to your angular client. You process the posted data in your backend and use a web socket to push or long polling to pull the result to your angular client

Comment: Building on @Lapskaus answer... you don't need a socket or long polling. If you're using Angular Universal, or at least serving your Angular app via Node or .NET, you can have a server-side handler to process the data and then render your Angular app. The information you get from the server side can be set in session storage, for example, and then re-hydrated where you need it. There are a few possibilities.

Comment: Thanks @BrandonTaylor. I do have .NET as a API app running in the background. The issue I'm now thinking how to solve is, should I call specific .net endpoint once the bank will redirect to the OKurl and then try to get the data they provided in the .net controller?

Comment: I can't speak to a .NET-based solution, but in Node / Express I could catch the redirect from the Bank and perform whatever work is necessary, then call a method to render whatever Angular route I need. Hopefully you can find a similar strategy.